# How do I display a mixed mode assembly's version number is windows explorer?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, mixed-mode

Is there a way for the assembly/file version of a mixed mode assembly to be displayed in windows explorer? I'm trying to investigate some versioning issues and it would be much quicker if I could just glance at the version numbers of assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++/CLI projects need an old Win32 .rc file to achieve this (AssemblyInfo.cpp's info is only embedded in the manifest and thus can't be seen by Windows Explorer, IIRC).
Right-click your project in Visual Studio's solution explorer, Add->Resource->Version. I just tried it with one of our C++/CLI projects, which use unmanaged code and are built with the /clr switch.

Answer (score 0):

Add the relevant column (File Version, for example) by right-clicking on the headers in detail view, and selecting More... option.